# How to deploy to a common hostname in OpenShift?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, openshift

I'm using OCP ver 3.9 and using jenkins pipeline to deploy to OpenShift. Usually, when I expose a route via this code:

```
def app = openshift.newApp("${IMAGE}:${imageStreamTag}", "--name=${appName}${appMajorVersion}")
app.narrow("svc").expose()
```

The exposed route will have the convention http://appName-projectName-clusterName/ (e.g. http://service1-myopenshiftproject-openshift.development.company.com.au/)

What I need is for my applications to have a common hostname (I don't want to have the application name and project name in the main/parent url --the one after the http://... ) , something like

```
http://openshift.development.company.com.au
```

I read about the hostname parameter of the *oc create route* command and I tried it in the Jenkins pipeline. I'm also following this link https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/how-deploy-multiple-versions-api-using-paths-openshift though for a slightly different purpose (exposing multiple api version using paths)

```
def app = openshift.newApp("${IMAGE}:${imageStreamTag}", "--name=${appName}${appMajorVersion}")
app.narrow("svc").expose("--path=/api/${appName}/v${appMajorVersion}", "--hostname=openshift.development.company.com.au")
```

The service got exposed according to the OpenShift web console, but when I try clicking the url found in the Overview tab of the OpenShift web console which lists down all the applications, this is what I got:

This site can’t be reached openshift.development.company.com.au’s server IP address could not be found.

How can this be done? Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: Just because the OpenShift server can accept requests for that hostname, doesn't mean it actually exists. You will still need to create a DNS entry for the hostname that you're specifying.